# Why does Url.IsLocalUrl return false if the URL contains a fragment?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using `Url.IsLocalUrl` to check if the return URL passed to my authentication action is local or not. It works fine as long as there is no fragment in the URL. That is,
`/t/test-team-3/tasks/lists/15` returns true, but `/t/test-team-3/tasks#/lists/15` returns false.

What's the reasoning behind this? Is there some obscure security issue that could manifest itself in the fragment, or can I safely ignore the fragment when I'm checking if the URL is local?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This method internally calls the [Uri.IsWellFormedUriString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring.aspx) method. When you call this method on a relative URL containing a fragment it returns false. There is [a bug on MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/94745/iswellformeduristring-does-not-accept-relative-urls-with-fragments) which is closed with the *by design* reason.

When you use this method on an absolute URL (with a scheme like http/https) the method behaves as expected. I think the reason is that the Uri class is intended to work not only with HTTP URLs. When you don't specify the protocol (relative URL), a generic URL parser is used which doesn't allow fragments.

So I guess you have two possibilities:

- Strip the fragment before calling the method
- Call the method on an absolute URL (`http://foo.com/t/test-team-3/tasks#/lists/15`) because anyway if you are calling this method on a relative URL we can expect that it is a local URL.

Comment: Are there other side effects when calling the method on localhost with a port?