# returnUrl and IsLocalUrl()

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am passing the `returnUrl = Request.Url` to a controller action, the problem is that when I check it with the following code before redirecting, it fails because of the `IsLocalUrl()` call. Why?

```
if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
   {
      return Redirect(returnUrl);
   }
```

Thanks.

Comment: It's failing in the sense that returns false? May it be something related to this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633782/why-does-url-islocalurl-return-false-if-the-url-contains-a-fragment ?

Comment: Yes, and the URL is absolutely fine: `http://localhost:55058/Orders/Details/102064`. What exactly means 'local' in this context?

Comment: Looking at the `IsReturnUrl` implementation (https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.WebPages/RequestExtensions.cs), it seems to consider local only things that start with `/` and `~/` (but not `//` or `/\`. You should probably trim the protocol:domain part of the url...

Comment: Note that the above is a change in MVC after 3 I think, since in MVC3 (as the SO answer explains) using absolute URL will work.

Comment: How do I get a local URL from `Request` class? I also tried `Request.RawUrl()` without success.

Comment: Best option is to create a new `Uri` object (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) and get the path: `new Uri(returnUrl).AbsolutePath` and pass this into `IsLocalUrl()`

Answer (score 8):

The problem was simply that `Url.IsLocalUrl()` returns true for URLs like `/Orders/Details/5326` and false for URLs like `http://www.company.com/Orders/Details/5326`

Comment: To explain the problem:
That method checks if url is a relative url. If it's an absolute url, that method retuns false.