# Why Url.IsLocalUrl is false for local URLs in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, owasp

## Mission:

To prevent [open redirection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Open_redirect) in an [ASP.NET MVC 5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc5) application

## The story:

The user is on some webpage of website `/`, say *overview* page `/Home/Overview` and clicks  <kbd>login</kbd>

After login, the server returns some *top-secret* user specific data and redirects to the same page from where the user initiated login request.

I need to make sure that the server do not **stupidly** redirect to a hacker's website after login and also pass *top-secret* user specific data.

The values of

- `_Controller.Request.UrlReferrer`
- `_Controller.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri`
- `_Controller.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri`
- `_Controller.Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl)`

respectively are:

- `{https://localhost:44300/Home/Overview}`
- `"https://localhost:44300/Home/Overview"`
- `"https://localhost:44300/Account/Login?returnUrl=%2FHome%2FOverview"`
- `false`

[image: values for redirection]

The value of `Url.IsLocalUrl` is false which is logically wrong.

In such case, how do I make sure that the user get safely redirected to `/Home/Overview` and not http://blackHatHackerWebsite.com after successful login?

## Why Url.IsLocalUrl is false for local URLs in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: have you tried these solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642436/urlhelper-islocalurl-method-always-returns-false-for-non-ascii-strings   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633782/why-does-url-islocalurl-return-false-if-the-url-contains-a-fragment

Comment: @karthiksubramaniam Let me see them

Comment: Your don't show the code you use to gets value for returnUrl.

Answer (score 7):

`Url.IsLocalUrl("/Home/Overview")` is definitely `true`. You get `false` because it's evaluating `Url.IsLocalUrl("%2fHome%2fOverview")`. That is, you `returnUrl` is url encoded twice. Try to find where you have an unnecessary encode.

Comment: I may be not doing any dual Url encoding. Btw, I'll surely review my code. Thanks!! Btw, I'm reading the [posts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34714789/why-url-islocalurl-is-false-for-local-urls-in-asp-net-mvc/34715197#comment57176098_34714789) referred by [@karthiksubramaniam](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4018620)

Comment: Not sure where is double encoding is. was not able to check if the url is local using this, I would love to see an example.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the ping method  If the result of the received ping address was successful That is, the address sent in the ReturnUrl variable is fake

```
// ` If reply.Status == IPStatus.Success`
//This means that the address entered in ReturnUrl is not local

private async Task<bool> ping_url(string url)
{
    Ping pingSender = new Ping();
    string host = url;
    bool res = true;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(host);
        /// if IPStatus.Success 
        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            res = true;   
        else  
            res = false;  
    });

    return res;
}
```